# react-bootstrap contains no css

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

my jsx file successfully recognizes the react-bootstrap elements but there's no styling to them. my project's node-modules folder contains both react-bootstrap and bootstrap. why is this happening?

```
var React = require('react');
var Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;
var Jumbotron = require('react-bootstrap').Jumbotron;

var ReactComponentHi = React.createClass({displayName: 'Hi',

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button bsStyle='success'>
                    clickk
                </Button>
                <Jumbotron>
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
                    <p><Button bsStyle='primary'>Learn more</Button></p>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>

        );
    }
});

module.exports = ReactComponentHi;
```

[image: what the results look like]

Comment: Have you included Bootstrap's CSS on your page?

Comment: @BenFortune

so i added the following line to my index.html and it worked.
'<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">'

Comment: @Simon if you make this an answer, you'll get pointz for ever after

Answer (score 11):

i added the following line to my index.html and it worked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, importing directly from the CDN is not needed, it's better to import the css from your local dist folder, to ensure the versions are the same.

Add this to your index.js / index.tsx below your other imports:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```